# Can't redirect aspx page to controller in .NET MVC 4 with url param

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to redirect requests made to an .aspx page to a controller in my MVC 4 .NET application.
Actually, I have a parameter passed via GET to the URL like this:

```
myPage.aspx?param1=helloworld
```

In my controller, I have the following action

```
class MyController : Controller
{
    public void MyAction(string param1)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

In RouteConfig.cs I've tried the following cases, but any of this options worked. I can't find information about how to pass url encoded GET paramters. (Also I got a 404 error if I try to access the aspx page without parameters and redirect to a controller action without parameters.

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        [...]

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "name",
           url: "myPage.asp.aspx",
           defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "MyAction", param1 = "defaultValue" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "name",
           url: "myPage.asp.aspx{value}",
           defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "MyAction", param1 = "defaultValue" }
        );


       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "name",
           url: "myPage.asp.aspx?value={value}",
           defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "MyAction", param1 = "defaultValue" }
        );


    }
}
```

How can I get this working (I explicity need to pass de value in the URL in that form)

Thanks

Comment: `defaults: new { controller = "MyController", ...` should be `defaults: new { controller = "My", ...`

Comment: Sorry, I re-wrote the code in the editor to give standard names to controllers and actions... and I forgot to write it properly

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you redirect in the controller action method, not in the routing configuration, the routing configuration is for...well, routing and configuration of routes...

Comment: Well, the problem is that I need to redirect the calls to this aspx page to a controlle action and get this parameter value. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I think the issue is not on your RouteConfig but in your web.config you need to tell IIS that .aspx are not to be processed normally but passed to MVC instead. it has something to do with system.webServer->handlers I can't do a propper response now but ill try latter but go to IIS and remove the *.aspx and add it again for the type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"

Answer (score 1):

In myPage.aspx:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.someMVC4site.com/my/MyAction/helloworld");
```

In RouteConfig.cs of MVC4 project

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "name",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}",
       defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "MyAction", param1 = "defaultValue" }
    );
```

Comment: myPage.aspx really doesn't exits, and I don't want It to exist. Finally I got it without handling parameters, only with  'url:mypage.aspx' and 'defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "MyAction"'. I need to mantain this redirection without the existence of mypage.aspx. Thanks.